# How to render assets (images) in rich text coming from Contentful

Tags: twig, contentful, richtext

I've set up Contentful as the headless CMS of my blog. Everything works, except rendering assets (in my case images specifically). My blog is built using Symfony and uses Twig for templating.

This is how (a part of the) content is currently rendered:

[image]

I'm using Contentful's default rich text renderer for Twig, as described [here](https://github.com/contentful/rich-text.php#twig-integration). Unfortunately, it doesn't say anything about assets. But given that there's an [EmbeddedImage](https://github.com/contentful/rich-text.php/blob/master/src/NodeRenderer/EmbeddedImage.php) class available, I would expect support for images.

What step am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a custom renderer for the assets in the same way as described for a custom heading [here](https://github.com/contentful/rich-text.php#twig-integration).

The reason why assets don't work "out of the box" is that the renderer can't know what type of asset is being returned. For example, is it a `.jpg`, `.mp4`, `.wav` file etc. You may have a variety of different assets in your Rich Text and will need to render the different asset files accordingly to your HTML.

The full list of node types you can define custom renderers for is [here](https://github.com/contentful/rich-text.php/tree/master/src/Node).

Comment: Thanks, got it working by registering it as a custom renderer.